# Update Transformations in Glide with new values

Tags: android, image-processing, transformation, android-glide

I am using Glide to load in images in my Android app, and I am using bitmapTransform to apply filters to the bitmaps. Kind of like an image sharing app where you get to chose from different effects when you upload a new image. My problem is, I can't find a way to update the transformations with new values. For example, I have "ColorFilter" effect...

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(mainPhoto)
     .apply(bitmapTransform(new ColorFilterTransformation(Color.argb(90, 255, 0, 0)))
     .into(base);
```

That will add the color filter transform with an extremely high red value. So if the user selects the color filter image, I apply the color filter transform to the main image, and then show the user sliders for red, green, and blue. What I can't figure out is how to update the values of the color filter transform after the user moves the sliders for each individual color. I hope I am making sense here, I will do a simplified layout and code to help illustrate what I am trying to accomplish..

So, let's say the user selects the color filter transformation, I apply color filter transformation to the main image, then show sliders for each color...

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/color_options_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lnl"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/seek_red"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Red"/>
                <SeekBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/seekbar_red"
                    android:max="255"
                    android:progress="255"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/seek_blue"
                    android:text="Blue"/>
                <SeekBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/seekbar_blue"
                    android:max="255"
                    android:progress="0"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/seek_green"
                    android:text="Green"/>
                <SeekBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/seekbar_green"
                    android:max="255"
                    android:progress="0"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Then in my code I have the on seekbar change listener to detect the user moving the slider..

```
redBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar_red);
redBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        redBarLabel(setText("Red: " + i);
        //Need to update the transformation of the image when the user changes slider here.
    }
    ...
}
```

I know that might be a bit much for processing, so maybe I can add the update to the "onStopTrackingTouch" part of the event listener? Either way, is there some way to just update the values of the transformation, or do I need to use `Glide.with(context).load(image).apply(...).into(view);` 
for every single time I need to update the transformations? That seems like it would be extremely expensive and a terrible user experience. Thank you for any help, and if you need any more code or anything, please ask, I will be more than happy to show you whatever code you need. Thank you.